# EJB 3 can implement 2 remote interfaces?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I have 2 remote interfaces, say `Example.java` and `RealExample.java`. My bean `Bean.java` is implementing those 2 remote interfaces.

According to the EJB 3.0 spec we can implement 2 remote interfaces in a single bean. My first interface is in `a.jar` and the other interface is in `b.jar`.

How can I make sure that the respective stubs are generated in `aclient.jar` and `bClient.jar`. I dont want my stubs to be in single jar.

Comment: I think this is not possible. If you really want to split the JARs you may need to cut-and-paste the files from one project into the other. Hope you're aware of the fact that this can easily become a maintenance nightmare...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, EJB 3 can implement two remote interfaces.  How stubs are generated and in which JARs the stubs are placed is beyond the scope of the EJB specification: it is vendor specific.

I can say that the WebSphere Application Server createEJBStubs tool will generate stubs in the same JAR as the interfaces themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Since the addition of dynamic proxies in the JDK and [dynamic RMI-IIOP](http://blogs.oracle.com/ejcorba/entry/dynamic_rmi_iiop) (2006), modern application servers do not require the **ancient** concept of manually generating stubs (let alone the even older concept of skeletons).

E.g. for at least JBoss AS 4.x+, [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#RMIStubsNeeded) and partially [WebSphere 7](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/cejb_deployejbfp.html) all you need to include in your client jars are the interfaces. Nothing else is needed. *(Unfortunately, for some unknown reason WebSphere only implements this relatively simple feature partially, so if you're using WebSphere and have a Java SE client, I feel your pain)*

Btw, also note that the proxy that you retrieve from the remote server can be directly casted to the interface. No `PortableRemoteObject` (another **ancient** concept) or anything like it is needed.